# Model a JSON file into a new one

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, file, dictionary

I have this JSON file:

```
{
    "annotations": [{
        "title": "Autismo",
        "spot": "Autismo",
        "uri": "http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autismo",
        "categories": ["Autismo", "Disturbi psichici", "Malattie del sistema nervoso", "Pediatria"]
    }, {
        "title": "Tablet computer",
        "spot": "tablet",
        "uri": "http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tablet_computer",
        "categories": ["Computer tablet"]
    }, {
        "title": "Diagnosi",
        "spot": "diagnosi precoce",
        "uri": "http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagnosi",
        "categories": ["Semeiotica", "Diagnostica medica"]
    }]
}
```

My target is to parse the JSON file and to create a new one with a changed structure like this:

```
     {u'http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autismo': {'spot': u'autistica',
                                                'title': u'Autismo'
                                                'categories':["Autismo", "Disturbi psichici", "Malattie del sistema nervoso", "Pediatria"]},
```

And so on for every dictionary into annotations.

My code is this:

```
diz={}
values = json.load(jsonFile)
for key in values["annotations"]:
    uri= key["uri"]
    ddd=key["categories"]

    diz[uri]={"title":key["title"],"spot":key["spot"],"categories":ddd} 

print diz
```

But when I run the code it gives me an error on `ddd=key["categories"]`. I think that I don't get in a correct way the values of "categories".

Can somebody help me in this?

Comment: What error do you get, exactly?

Comment: Not really sure I understand why you want the URI as the key of the dictionary

Comment: I get:                                                                                                         KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-4f82af6494ef> in <module>()
      6                 for key in values["annotations"]:
      7                     uri= key["uri"]
----> 8                     ddd=key["categories"]
      9                     #ddd=key["categories"]
     10                     #cat=ddd["categories"]

KeyError: 'categories' . It's like I can't store the values of "categories" into ddd.